# Best Practice in reusing Installed Packages

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, journeybuilder

I've created an installed package which is being used for a Journey Builder Entry Source Component. Can I reuse the same installed package for multiple journey API entries? Is there a best practice or recommendation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can re-use your installed package for other Journey Builder events or integrations. I'm not sure there's a definitive best practice on managing your installed packages, but my personal preference is for creating a separate package for each system or vendor that's integrating with your Salesforce Marketing Cloud account. In this way, auditing your API traffic at some later date would be easier and if you need to revoke access to a specific system or vendor you can do so easily without affecting others.